# how to compare two strings in system call

Tags: c, string

```
    #define O_WRONLY    01
    #define O_APPEND    02000

    int main(void)
    {
        // fd is an indentifier for the file that we are going to work with
        int fd;
        // We open the file with the write or append mode, so you will
        // have to create the file testfile.txt in the current directory.
        fd = open("jobby.txt", O_WRONLY|O_APPEND, 0);


        if(fd < 0)
            return 2;
         char str[10]= "";  
      char buf1[] = "Please type username and hit Enter: ";
      write(1, buf1, sizeof(buf1));
       read (0, str, 10);
      write(fd,str, sizeof(str));

     char str1[10]= "";  
      char buf2[] = "Please type in a password and hit Enter: ";
      write(1, buf2, sizeof(buf2));
       read (0, str1, 10);
      write(fd,str1, sizeof(str));

    char str2[10]= "";  
      char buf4[] = "Please re-enter password and hit Enter: ";
      write(1, buf4, sizeof(buf4));
       read (0, str2, 10);
      write(fd,str2, sizeof(str));

    if(sizeof(str1)==sizeof(str2))
    {
    char buf5[] = "\n password match: ";
      write(1, buf5, sizeof(buf5)); 
    }
    else
    {
    char buf6[] = "\n password mismatch: ";
      write(1, buf6, sizeof(buf6)); 
    }
```

I wrote a system call program.I have to compare two passwords but this code is not working.How i can compare two strings? This comparing function is not working.Otherwise the code is perfect.

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: The posted code is making the assumption that the number of characters in user name is exactly 10 and the number of characters in password is exactly 10.  Unless there is a restriction that isn't mentioned in the question, that is a very risky assumption.

Comment: regarding this line: 'if(sizeof(str1)==sizeof(str2))' Since both str1 and str2 are declared as 10 byte arrays, this will always be 'true'

Comment: the test for password match needs to call strncmp(), not look at the size of the buffers

Comment: You really need to compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`), to [RTFM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM) in particular [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html), and to **use the debugger** (`gdb`). Don't expect us to find *your* bugs. Your code is imperfect, full of [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Comment: this kind of line: char str[10]= "";  results in a '\0' placed in the first character of the str[] array.  A better method is: char str[10] = {'\0'}; which fills the array with all '\0' characters.

Answer (score 3):

```
if(sizeof(str1)==sizeof(str2))
```

Instead of comparing the size of the buffers, you can make use of function [`strcmp()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcmp.htm) -

```
if(strcmp(str1,str2)==0){
    //your code
}
```

Header file - [`string.h`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/string_h.htm)

This function returns `0` if both strings are equal.

### EDIT

But you need to add `'\0'` at end of strings as `read()` will not append it.

Increase size of arrays to `11`. 
Add `'\0'` at end of char arrays `str1` and `str2`.

Comment: the read() function does not append a '\0' on the end of the string so strcmp() will fail as it is not comparing valid strings

Comment: the OPs posted code is not comparing the size of the strings,  rather it is comparing the size of the buffer declarations (which happen to both be 10 characters)

Comment: @user3629249  Yes thank you for your inputs .I will edit answer accordingly.

Comment: But `strcmp()` is not a system call  ;-)

Comment: strcmp() is not working.actually i tried it.can anyone suggest a  a system call fn to compare these strings